# angularjs 'bindings' in component doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components

```
.component(
  'testComponent',
 {bindings: {name:'<'},
  template: `{{$ctrl.name}}<br/>
             {{$ctrl.title}}<br/>
             {{test.name}}<br/>
             {{test.title}}<br/>
             {{name}}<br/>
             {{title}}<br/>`,
  controller: function (){
    this.name = 'abc';
    this.title = 'def';
  },
  controllerAs: 'test'
})
```

This code is to add a component to a module.
There are written 6 expressions in template. But only second one, `$ctrl.title` is working well. The others are not binded properly.
When I remove `name` from `bindings`, then `$ctrl.name` also works well. But AFAIK all the 6 expressions have to work.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: **Don't** say it "doesn't work" and leave it is that. **Describe the problem**. Describe what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because here the binding `'<'` means one way binding
Where are you using this component
The name binding should be passed  from where you are calling this component
eg

```
<test-component>name='abc' </test-component>
```

This will work also remove controllerAs = test,if you are using `$cntrl` as it is default controllerAs of component and you are replacing it with `test`

Comment: I should have shown you the full source code. I already tested '=', '=?' and '@'. Only '=?' works even that the value is not watched after initialization. I think not giving bindings option and giving it as '=?' work same, but it does not reflect the value changed after initalized once.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression
I think my component works in the 'one-time binding' way, while it is not inteded.